# Error on browser: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, web-config

I am working with the OAuth2 Authorization server & Resource server. For web configuration, I am extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` class and using `@EnableWebMvc` annotation on my `WebConfig` class. The code is working fine but whenever I am trying to hit the URL I am getting this error message on the browser saying: **This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.**

**<error_description>Full authentication is required to access this resource</error_description>
unauthorized**

Here is my class:

```java
package com.ab.security.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {


    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        super.addViewControllers(registry);

        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index");

        registry.addViewController("/index");
        registry.addViewController("/secure");

    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }

}
```

Here is My OauthConfig.java file:

```
package com.ab.security.config;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration
public class OauthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

    }
}
```

Here is AuthorizationServerConfig.java:

```
package com.ab.security.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;

@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("ClientId").secret("secret").authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .scopes("user_info").autoApprove(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
    
}
```

Here is ResourceServerConfig.java file:

```
package com.ab.security.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;

@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize").and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().formLogin().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean()).inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Peter")
                .password("peter").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot then why this config? Remove `@EnableWebMvc` remove all the overridden method but the `addViewControllers` (all the rest is done by Spring Boot already). If that doesn't fix it the error is in your security setup and not so much in your web setup.

Comment: @M.Deinum ,  I have done as you suggested but now i am getting this one:  Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread;

Comment: Then re-add the `RequestContextListener` bean.

Comment: @M.Deinum If I re-add the ```RequestContextListener``` then again the main problem still persists for which I have post this question.

Comment: I Am following this [Tutorials](http://example.com), but just updated the Boot version to ```2.3.3 RELEASE```

Comment: If you still have the same issue then your spring security configuration isn't correct.

Comment: @M.Deinum sir, I have Updated my question with security configuration files, These are the only main configuration files. Could you please help where and what should I change?

Comment: You require to be authenticated for al rules and your config only applies to `/login` and `/oauth/authorize`. So not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @M.Deinum sir, I am new to OAuth2, and i am just trying to understand [This](https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-security-oauth-example) tutorial code. This code is working perfectly but it is in  boot ```1.5.6.RELEASE``` and i updated it to ```2.3.3.RELEASE```. I am using thymeleaf UI just want to know why i am getting this XML file issue.

Comment: Because you have secured everything even the login.